# Read memory mapped file to string

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to read data from a memory mapped file, which is written to the memory file from a C++ program. I am able to use the debug method and write the data as a string from a loop. However, I want to convert the byte array to a usable string that I can then manipulate.

```
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("DataFile"))
{
    using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor reader = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
    {
        var bytes = new byte[reader.Capacity];
        reader.ReadArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        for(int i = 0; i<bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write((char) bytes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried removing the for loop and replacing it with a GetString() encoder, but it only returns a question mark character instead of the full data string.

Comment: Take a look at this article, maybe it will help you https://csharpvault.com/blog/memory-mapped-files

Answer (score 3):

So long as you know the encoding the bytes were written with this is easy, you would use for example the System.Text.UTF8Encoding class (probably the System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 instance) and the  GetString method:

```
string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

If you don't know the encoding this becomes much harder, you would have to try and use a heuristic method and guess what the encoding actually is.